# Need help transposing data from one column based on criteria SQL

Tags: sql, data-analysis

I'm challenged with summarising the total estimated machine time vs the total actual machine time for a list of jobs based on a date field.  The issue is that all estimate and actual entries are in one column.

I need help transposing this data into separate columns for easier analysis.

This is a simplified example of what the table looks like...

| JobNo | OperationDesc | OperationLength | Quantity | PostingType | StartDateAndTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 345271 | Durst 1330: MR | 0.33 | 1 | 1 | 2021-04-27 16:00 |
| 345271 | Durst 1330: Run | 1.5 | 15 | 1 | 2021-04-27 16:00 |
| 345271 | Durst3 IDC | 0.5 | 3 | 2 | 2021-04-28 10:00 |
| 345271 | Durst3 IDC | 0.75 | 5 | 2 | 2021-04-28 11:00 |
| 345271 | Durst3 IDC | 1 | 10 | 2 | 2021-04-28 12:00 |

PostingType "1" is the estimate and "2" is actual.

What I'm trying to get is a table looking like this....

| JobNo | EstimatedMachine | EstimatedTime | QuantityOrdered | MachineUsed | TotalTime | TotalQuantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 345271 | Durst 1330 | 1.83 | 15 | Durst3 | 2.25 | 18 |

The code I've worked out so far is this..

```
SELECT JobNo
      ,(SELECT TOP 1 LEFT(OperationDesc, CHARINDEX(':', OperationDesc)-1) FROM TSE WHERE PostingType = '1') [MachineEstimated]
      ,(SELECT SUM(OperationLength) FROM TSE WHERE PostingType = '1') [EstimatedTime]
      ,(SELECT SUM(Quantity) FROM TSE WHERE PostingType = '1' AND OperationDesc NOT LIKE '%MR%') [QuantityOrdered]
      ,(SELECT TOP 1 LEFT(OperationDesc, CHARINDEX(' ', OperationDesc)-1) FROM TSE WHERE PostingType = '2') [MachineUsed]
      ,(SELECT SUM(OperationLength) FROM TSE WHERE PostingType = '2') [TotalTime]
      ,(SELECT SUM(Quantity) FROM TSE WHERE PostingType = '2') [TotalQuantity]
FROM TSE
WHERE StartDateAndTime >= '2021-04-28T06:00:00.000' 
AND StartDateAndTime <= '2021-04-29T59:59:00.000' 
GROUP BY JobNo
```

The results I get do only include the job numbers that ran (PostingType 2) in the day selected (28th) but the other columns sum the total of the entire table and only pull through the first OperationDesc of the table rather than only the 24 hour day specified.

What I'm I doing wrong? Is there a better way to get what I need?

Many thanks,

Comment: Your code is not valid MySQL code.  Please fix the database tag so it represents the database you are really using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT JobNo,
       MAX(CASE WHEN PostingType = 1 THEN LEFT(OperationDesc, CHARINDEX(':', OperationDesc) - 1) END) as MachineEstimated,
       SUM(CASE WHEN PostingType = 1 THEN OperationLength END) as EstimatedTime,
       SUM(CASE WHEN PostingType = 1 Quantity END) as QuantityOrdered,
       MAX(CASE WHEN PostingType = 2 THEN LEFT(OperationDesc, CHARINDEX(':', OperationDesc) - 1) END) as MachineUsed,
       SUM(CASE WHEN PostingType = 2 THEN OperationLength END) as TotalTime,
       SUM(CASE WHEN PostingType = 2 Quantity END) as TotalQuantity
FROM TSE
WHERE StartDateAndTime >= '2021-04-28T06:00:00.000' AND
      StartDateAndTime <= '2021-04-29T59:59:00.000' 
GROUP BY JobNo;
```

Note:  `PostingType` looks like a number, so I dropped the single quotes.  If it is really a string, then use the single quotes.  Don't mix data types.

Comment: Hi there! I've edited my code and tried your suggestion and it worked - although with a lot of NULL values - so more digging through the data for me :p Many thanks!

Comment: One small issue that I'm still struggling to resolve is that the query pulls through PostingType 2 and PostingType1 data for the same specified date, whereas I want to pull through PostingType2 data from the specified date and pull through the PostingType1 data by the associated JobNo, which would have been created on a different date. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Abi . . . Move the date condition from the `WHERE` clause to the `WHEN` conditions for `1`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? I added the date parameter after PostingType = 2 in the CASE clause, but it didn't change the results.  I'm not sure about putting a date condition in the WHEN clause of PostingType = 1 as I wouldn't know when these data entries were made.

Comment: In my mind, the logic to link PostingType 1 and 2 is the JobNo.  Is there something I could add into the CASE clause of PostingType 1 that would link it to the JobNo of PostingType 2?